# Can I have Mathematica show intermediate forms before final evaluation?

Tags: evaluation

If I have

```
x = 2
```

and I want to evaluate

```
y = x^2
```

I would like to the output to show

```
y = (2)^2
```

before evaluating to 4.

Comment: Define `y[x_] := x^2 // HoldForm` and then use `y[2]` to get 2^2 and `y[2] // ReleaseHold` to get 4.

Comment: Take a look at `Defer` too.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to look into new functions that are already available on [**Raspberry Pi**](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi) and you have something to look forward to in a general future release: [**Activate**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html), [**Inactive**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and [**Inactivate**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html).

They are a very powerful way to transform the code and expressions in the way you need. For example.

```
f[x_] := Inactive[Power][x, 2]

y == f[2]
```

> y == 2^2

```
y == Activate@f[2]
```

> y == 4

You can make a lot of things including identity tables:

```
Table[f[k] == Activate[f[k]], {k, 0, 3}] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Table[Inactive[Sin][k \[Pi]/6] == Sin[k \[Pi]/6], {k, 0, 3}] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

But in your specific case you of course could simply do something like:

```
Table[Superscript[k, 2] == k^2, {k, 0, 3}] // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: I'm happy it seems to work as I've imagined it works :) Can't wait to test it.

Answer (score 2):

As Boson suggested, [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReleaseHold.html) can be pressed into service to accomplish what you ask. Here is how you can use them.

```
ySq[x_] := Module[{y}, Row[{"y = ", y = HoldForm[x^2], " = ", ReleaseHold[y]}]]
Column[ySq /@ Range[5]]
```

> ```
> y = 1^2 = 1
> y = 2^2 = 4
> y = 3^2 = 9
> y = 4^2 = 16
> y = 5^2 = 25
> ```

`ySq` can serve as a model for defining other functions that can produce similar expository output.